# How do I exclude a character in Linux

Tags: linux

Write a wildcard to match all files (does not matter the files are in which directory, just ask for the wildcard) named in the following rule: starts with a string “image”, immediately followed by a one-digit number (in the range of 0-9), then a non-digit char plus anything else, and ends with either `“.jpg”` or `“.png”.`  For example, `image7.jpg` and image0abc.png should be matched by your wildcard while `image2.txt` or `image11.png` should not.

My folder contained these files `imag2gh.jpeg`   `image11.png`   `image1agb.jpg`   `image1.png`   `image2gh.jpg`   `image2.txt`   `image5.png`   `image70.jpg`   `image7bn.jpg`  `Screenshot .png`

If my command work it should only display `image1agb.jpg`  `image1.png`  image2gh.jpg  image5.png  image70.jpg  image7bn.jpg

This is the command I used `(ls -ad image[0-9][^0-9]*{.jpg,.png})`                                                                                                                                                                                           but I'm only getting this `image1agb.jpg` `image2gh.jpg` `image7bn.jpg` so I'm missing `(image1.png image5.png)`[Kali Terminal and what I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck6n3.png)

`ls -ad image[0-9][!0-9]*{.jpg,.png}`

Comment: RegEx character ranges won't work for shell globbing like that.

Comment: You will probably need to improve your question a bit... If you explain what you are trying to do, it will be easier for other users to help you... Improving the grammar a bit would also help a lot...

Comment: I added more info now and a screenshot of my terminal

Comment: Why is `image70.jpg` part of the output? `0` is definitely a digit after `7`. Could you clear up your post? Please write which files there are, which files you want to get, in a code block. Your regex `image[0-9][!0-9]*{.jpg,.png}` should have worked, isn't it correct?

Answer (score 0):

## Info

Character ranges like [0-9] are usually seen in RegEx statements and such. They won't work as shell globs (wildcards) like that.

## Possible solution

1. Pipe output of command `ls -a1`
   to **standard input** of the `grep` command (which **does** support RegEx).
2. Use a RegEx statement to make `grep` filter filenames.

```sh
ls -a1|grep "image"'[[:digit:]]\+[[:alpha:]]*\.\(png\|jpg\)'
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it did work , so there is no really way to make it work with just the ls command and  the alpha represent the nonnumerical character I guess.

Comment: No. As i stated. You can't use RegEx directly in shell.

Comment: I'd suggest using `find` instead of `ls -al`